# Бонусы в арканоиде на Unity

Tags: unity3d

Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы при поднятии бонуса в арканоиде, шарик становился триггером и пролетал (уничтожал) **только блоки**, но отскакивал как коллайдер от стен и платформы. Пытался сделать это кучей способов, но все они работали неправильно. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: В случае с арканойдом вы вообще не должны использовать физику юнити. Расчёт столкновение ровного прямоугольника с кругом это не тревиальная задача.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавь на стены отдельный физический слой и в настройках физики для шарика поставь игнорирование этого слоя. Когда действие бонуса закончится (если конечно оно закончится) то возращай ему предыдущее значение слоев

Comment: а как это сделать? где это настраивается?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html

Comment: спасибо, теперь работает. а как сделать отслеживание столкновения в коде, если OnCollisionEnter2D не будет работать?

Comment: нужно ведь как то разрушать объекты.

Comment: Как врянт можно добавить для объекта без колюзии дочерний у которого колюзия будет включена, и уже по этому объекту определять столкновение

Comment: Если вы разрушаете объекты то тогда такой прием нужно применять на игрока (объект который через них проходит)

Comment: шарик должен просто лететь и разрушать блоки, не сталкиваясь

Comment: хотя я примерно понял, как это сделать. Спасибо.